# Appending float to list of dates

Tags: python, list

I have some lists of np.datetimes and I would like to append a float to them:

```
list_of_floats=[0.01,0.02,0.01]

list1=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list2=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list3=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list_of_lists=[list1,list2,list3]
```

This is what i tried:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_floats)):
    list_of_lists[i].append(list_of_floats[i])

print(list_of_lists)
```

desired output:

```
[[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),np.datetime64('2017-03-01'),0.01],
[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),np.datetime64('2017-03-01'),0.02]
[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),np.datetime64('2017-03-01'),0.01]]
```

How could i overcome this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In what way should the float be added to the date and what is the expected outcome? Currently the `[i]` subscript is a float object rather than an integer index, which will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

list_of_floats=[0.01,0.02,0.01]

list1=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list2=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list3=[np.datetime64('2016-07-01'),
       np.datetime64('2017-03-01')]

list_of_lists=[list1,list2,list3]

for i, v in enumerate(list_of_floats):
    list_of_lists[i].append(v)

print(list_of_lists)
```

---

or using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
for i, v in zip(list_of_floats, list_of_lists):
    v.append(i)
```

**Output:**

```
[[numpy.datetime64('2016-07-01'), numpy.datetime64('2017-03-01'), 0.01],
 [numpy.datetime64('2016-07-01'), numpy.datetime64('2017-03-01'), 0.02],
 [numpy.datetime64('2016-07-01'), numpy.datetime64('2017-03-01'), 0.01]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `zip`

```py
import numpy as np

list_of_floats=[0.01, 0.02, 0.01]
list_of_lists=[
    [np.datetime64('2016-07-01'), np.datetime64('2017-03-01')],
    [np.datetime64('2016-07-01'), np.datetime64('2017-03-01')],
    [np.datetime64('2016-07-01'), np.datetime64('2017-03-01')],
]

for date_list, float_number in zip(list_of_lists, list_of_floats):
    date_list.append(float_number)

print(list_of_lists)
```